# HTML page won't load image when sent through socket java

Tags: java, html, sockets, client-server

I have this simple HTML that loads how I want when I load it in Chrome.

```
<body>
    <div><h1>Welcome to my webpage!</h1></div>
    <div>This page is being hosted on the local machine.</div>
    <div>Now, here's a picture of a cat. Please enjoy.</div>
    <img src="cat.jpg" alt="Business Cat" width="800" height="600"/>
</body>
```

When I pass it through a socket in Java, I always get a broken image. I can't figure out why, because I'm just passing bytes through the socket.

```
File index = new File("index.html");

byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(index);

while (true)
{
    int read = in.read(bytes);
    if (read < 0)
         break;
    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
}

out.flush();
out.close();
```

The image file "cat.jpg" is in the same directory as "index.html". What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the fact that it sends another http request. You should make provision for example: 127.0.0.1/index.html to display your index.html file while 127.0.0.1/cat.jpg should return your picture.
I am not sure however how you would parse a jpg file in java.
But if you are in chrome and you go to inspect; and you go to network. From there if you reload, you will see a request for your picture is either pending, or not the correct information that you returned, depending on how you implemented our handling of http requests.